# How to add a Click event to an Ellipse in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, click

To add a click event to a Button in C# code behind, I can do this

```
Button btn = new Button;
btn.Click += btn_Click;
```

What if I have an Ellipse, which does not contain a Click?

```
Ellipse e = new Ellipse;
e.??? += e_Click;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the MouseUp event will serve your purpose.
Try

```
Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
ellipse.MouseUp += ellipse_MouseUp;

private void ellipse_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: MouseUp != Click, just saying.

Comment: @H.B. agreed but since there is no Click, you'll have to pick one of MouseUp, MouseDown, MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseLeftButtonUp, MouseRightButtonDown, MouseRightButtonUp.

Comment: I posed a question about this actually, you can create a click from those events or use behaviours, it's all a bit messy though, the cleanest thing would be to wrap it in a button but who knows if this would be an option here. (My Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830164/what-is-the-best-way-to-simulate-a-click-with-mouseup-mousedown-events-or-other )

Answer (score 8):

One way to do that is make button an ellipse and attatch .Click Event handler.

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Ellipse .../>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```