# How to draw an ellipse on position I touch Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I try to do something like when I touch somewhere on the screen - that position show up a circle

But the problem is - everywhere I touch the screen, the circle always appears in the middle of my grid:

```
public void Draw_Circle(int x, int y)
{
        SolidColorBrush scb_O = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        Ellipse elip = new Ellipse();

        elip.Stroke = scb_O;
        elip.StrokeThickness = 2;

        elip.Height = dd;
        elip.Width = dd;
        Canvas.SetLeft(elip, (double)x);
        Canvas.SetTop(elip, (double)y);
        //elip.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (double)x);
        //elip.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)y);

        try
        {
            ContentPanel.Children.Add(elip);
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex2);
        }
    }
```

And the touch position:

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

        Point p1 = e.GetPosition(null);
        int x = (int)p1.X;
        int y = (int)p1.Y;
        //MessageBox.Show(x + " , " + y + "\n" + p1.X + " , " + p1.Y);

        Draw_Circle(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elip.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
elip.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
elip.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform() { X = 10, Y = 50 }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse(v=vs.110).aspx
[How to add a Click event to an Ellipse in code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560952/how-to-add-a-click-event-to-an-ellipse-in-code-behind)

Combine these two resourses and implemente them to solve your own problem. First resource shows how to create an ellipse and second resource shows how to call it with a event handler. I hope it may work and help you..