# LeftClick firing on mouse down?

Tags: wpf, binding, gestures

I am binding a left click gesture to a WPF button, expecting that it only fires when the mouse is clicked (MouseDown+MouseUp).  However, it appears to fire immediately upon pressing the mouse button down (without releasing).

1. Is this the correct way to bind to a left click?
2. How do I differentiate between a click and a press in the event handler?

Sample code:

```
public partial class WpfTest : UserControl
{
    // Gesture for clicking
    public static MouseGesture MouseClickGesture = new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick);

    // Logon command/gesture binding
    public static RoutedUICommand LogonCommand = new RoutedUICommand();
    public static MouseBinding LogonClickBinding = new MouseBinding(LogonCommand, MouseClickGesture);


    public WpfTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(LogonCommand, LogonClicked));
        Logon.InputBindings.Add(LogonClickBinding);
    }

    private void LogonClicked(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("LogonClicked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use those bindings, for all i know you can not get a proper click from them (seriously, who designed this?). From what i've seen it is suprisingly hard to get an [actual click on an arbitrary control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830164/what-is-the-best-way-to-simulate-a-click-with-mouseup-mousedown-events-or-other). I would suggest you wrap a Button around whatever you want to be clickable and use the Button's `Command` /`Click`-Event.

Change the Button's template to this to make it invisible:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <ContentPresenter/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I am using command bindings because I need to dynamically create some buttons at runtime, and I thought that this was the recommended way to do this kind of thing in WPF.  When creating buttons at runtime, I guess that you are suggesting I programmatically assign the Click event?

Comment: @Travis: You can also set the Command if you want to, depends on your use-case.

Comment: @Travis: Commands are objects which encapsulate a request, events just contain a list of methods to be called.