# WPF Determining DataTemplate object a user clicked on in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

Assume a simple MVVM Application implemented in WPF:

There is a view with an `ItemsControl` that uses `DataTemplate`s to resolve a view for various ViewModels in a collection.

What I want to know is, how would I add functionality to allow me to click on a given ViewModel in my `ItemsControl` to return that element in the container ViewModel?

That is to say, for the given example, I may want be able to click on my `WrapPanel` and then from my `BarnYardViewModel` have the particular ViewModel from the `ItemSource` tag returned. (much like binding the selected item in a `ComboBox`)

```
<UserControl x:Class="AGI_ServiceTool.View.DataMonitorView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModel">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MooCowViewModel}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/View/Images/MooCow.png"/>
                <label content="This is a Moo Cow"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ChickenViewModel}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/View/Images/Chicken.png"/>
                <label content="This is a Chicken"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:HorseViewModel}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/View/Images/SarahJessicaParker.png"/>
                <label content="This is a Horse"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyAnimals}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And a few basic ViewModels:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModel
{
    class AbstractViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged { ... }
    class MooCowViewModel   : AbstractViewModel {}
    class ChickenViewModel  : AbstractViewModel {}
    class HorseViewModel    : AbstractViewModel {}

    class BarnYardViewModel : AbstractViewModel 
    {
        public BarnYardViewModel()
        {
            _myAnimals.add(new MooCowViewModel());
            _myAnimals.add(new ChickenViewModel());
            _myAnimals.add(new HorseViewModel());
        }

        private ObservableCollection<AbstractViewModel> _myAnimals = new ObservableCollection<AbstractViewModel>();

        public ICollectionView MyAnimals{
            get { return System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_myAnimals); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the `DataTemplates` in `ItemsControl`?

Comment: By setting DataType in the DataTemplate, WPF is smart enough to resolve the correct template when I, `System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(...)`

Comment: And where you want to click? The actual items? `StackPanel` specifically and inside its children.

Comment: Sure! That (the `StackPanel`) would be a good representation of the item as a whole.

Comment: Sorry delayed answer, had to do something else. I answered your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a regular Button styled to have no UI, and would pass the `ViewModel` to it using the `CommandParameter`

For example,

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ContentOnlyTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <ContentPresenter />
</ControlTemplate>

... 

<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=MyItemsControl, Path=DataContext.MyClickCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                Template="{StaticResource ContentOnlyTemplate}"
                Content="{Binding }" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This will result in each item in your `ItemsControl` being rendered using a Button, and the Button will execute whatever command you specify and pass the current ViewModel in as the `CommandParameter`.

In this case, I've specified that the `Button.Template` should be overwritten to use a `ContentPresenter` which has no UI, so basically it will be whatever your `DataTemplate` for each animal is.

There are some other solutions posted at this related WPF question too if you're interested: [What is the best way to simulate a Click, with MouseUp & MouseDown events or otherwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4830164/302677)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I implemented your solution, but I ultimately ended up using a ListView and sticking my ItemsPanelTemplate inside of the ListView.ItemsPanel. I'm still sort of new and just feeling out WPF and MVVM, but this was good learning experience

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why it is a `StackPanel` yet you want something to know if it is `Clicked`?

I suggest you to change it to a `Button` and change the `Template` for it then hookup the `Command` property to a property in your `ViewModel` then said the `CommandParamter` as the `Type`

Comment: I wouldn't focus too much on the StackPanel. I just wanted to show that I had a container with more than one thing in it. My actual implementation has a grid. Thanks for your answer, and +1 because this is basically what I decided to go with.